# mobi file corrupted after php download

Tags: php, download, ftp

I have some ebooks on my server, that I want people to be able to download. I uploaded them and when I download them via my ftp tool then everything is perfect. when I use my script for the user to download it, then I get the following error in calibre:

```
MobiError: Unknown book type: '\x00\x00\x00BOOKM'
```

my script that handles the output of the file is as follows:

```
$file_url = ABSPATH . $file['file'];

$basename = $story->post_title . $subtitle . '.' . $_POST['type'];
$filename = basename(mb_ereg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;\[\]\(\).])", '', $basename));

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
die();
```

Then all mobi readers I got say, that there is a problem with the file. I don't know what is going wrong. Also when I open the files in a text editor they are both different type. The one from my php script looks as follows:

[image]

the one that works from my ftp tool looks like this:

[image]

Anyone who can help me to find what I am doing wrong? The .epub files by the way are no problem with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by outputting the file as follows:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path);
exit;
```